# Spring Application slow startup time using embedded jetty

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am dealing with a rather large web application based on Maven, Spring (3.1), Hibernate which is making use of aspects, ...
During development I am using eclipse and embedded jetty.
I am facing about 100 different maven artifacts.

Problem is that the local server startup time is very, very, very slow.

What I have found out until now is, that the more maven projects I have opened inside eclipse, the longer the jetty startup time is.
My guess it is something concerning classpath, resource loading, ...

The system is hanging for about one minute at the following line:
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext"...

Any advices on what to look for or what to tune in order to start the server faster?
My fear is that the aspects are slowing down the server startup... Could that be?

I now it is a very general question, but I am currently really stuck and looking for potential problems...
So any advice is deeply appreciated. ;)

Thanks for your help!
Stefan

Comment: What version of Jetty? and what version of the servlet spec? and are you using annotation scanning?

Comment: jetty 8, servlet 2.5 and yes

Comment: If you're on 2.5 there is no servlet annotation scanning.

Comment: Set your log level to debug/trace and see what happens.

Comment: logging is my approach, too
let me come back if i find something suspicious

Comment: enable DEBUG level logging for `org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration` you should see some events about what is going on.

Comment: An enhancement request for improving this logging has been filed at https://bugs.eclipse.org/424380

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to read anything useful from the log files. Only thing that caught my attention is that the classes are loaded about 200 times each.
Moreover the server startup (same settings) takes about 2 minutes on a Mac and about 7 minutes on a windows machine.
So I blame the file system - any advices?

Comment: we have about 400.000 objects on one single git repository
could this be of any effect on the slow class loading time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually it turned out it was the pointcuts of our aspects
they were not very specific, so every class was scanned via reflection for potential pointcut methods.
by making the aspects more specific we could achieve an immense boost in speedup of the sprint context!

Answer (score 1):

It's problably due to annotation scanning through all your classes as suggested here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Avoid_slow_deployment

You should be able to restrict which jars are scanned while deploying your webapp in jetty.